# JSON array convert to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, json

Hi. I got my output in JSON... Now I need to convert those data into javascript..

How to write the code in javascript?
I have to display the images to the browser.. it is possible only by writing the code in javascript.
Help me..

My JSON output is..

```
    [{"0":"101","member_id":"101","1":"3k.png","image_nm":"3k.png","2":"\/images\/phones\/","image_path":"\/images\/phones\/"},
     {"0":"102","member_id":"102","1":"mirchi.png","image_nm":"mirchi.png","2":"images\/phones\/","image_path":"images\/phones\/"},
     {"0":"103","member_id":"103","1":"masti.png","image_nm":"masti.png","2":"images\/phones\/","image_path":"images\/phones\/"}]
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> hai i got my output in **JSON**...now i need to convert those data into
>   javascript..

Use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON) function in order to convert it to JS object.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(yourJsonString);
```

And now you can use `for-in` loop to iterate over each of its items:

```
for (var x in obj){
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x)){
    // your code
  }
}
```

Comment: where should i write this function?

Comment: in the place of yourJsonString i need to write the whole json array??

Comment: @krishnabhargavi: Yes you are write. If your json is stored in a variable, you can then write that there too.

Comment: @krishnabhargavi: Yes can write it where your other JS code is in the correct context of your json string.

Comment: i created the js file i wrote all stuff what u said but the images are not displayed

Comment: @krishnabhargavi: For that problem you can ask another question (and accept one from here) because that is completely different problem.

Comment: ohk...but i want those images to be printed on the browser

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jQuery you can use

```
var object = $.parseJSON(jsonstring);
```

Or add this library https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js and give

```
var object = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
```

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to use it as an object, which supports all of the key functions of an array

Answer (score 1):

As Sarfraz is saying,

```
var jsonString = '[{"0":"101","member_id":"101","1":"3k.png","image_nm":"3k.png","2":"\/images\/phones\/","image_path":"\/images\/phones\/"},{"0":"102","member_id":"102","1":"mirchi.png","image_nm":"mirchi.png","2":"images\/phones\/","image_path":"images\/phones\/"},{"0":"103","member_id":"103","1":"masti.png","image_nm":"masti.png","2":"images\/phones\/","image_path":"images\/phones\/"}]';
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
// obj now contains the array!
```

EDIT: For it to display the images:

```
for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++){
    var img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute("src",obj[i][2] + obj[i][1]);
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Comment: Ohk..but i need the code to display the images to the browser.

Comment: @krishnabhargavi Where are the images stored?

Comment: @krishnabhargavi Please try to be more descriptive, where is this folder located? On your computer? On a server?

Comment: And where is that in relation to this file?

Answer (score -1):

Here are my two cents :

```js
var my_json = [{created_at: "2017-03-14T01:00:32Z", entry_id: 33358, field1: "4", field2: "4", field3: "0"},{created_at: "2019-03-14T01:00:32Z", entry_id: 33359, field1: "4", field2: "4", field3: "0"}];

var data =[];
var dataSet=[];
 my_json.forEach((val,index)=>{
  if(my_json[index]!==null){
   for(var i in my_json[index]) {
     data.push(my_json[index][i]);
   }
   dataSet.push(data);
   data=[];
  } 
 })
console.log("...java Script Array... \n"+JSON.stringify(dataSet));
```

Comment: You are converting a JavaScript array of objects to a JavaScript array of arrays. This is not what Krishna asked for. Your variable `my_json` does not hold JSON data.